# Split the index by nth delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split the index of `anno` dataframe by the 2nd occurrence of the `_` delimiter.

```
anno.index = ','.join(str(v) for v in anno.index)
'_'.join(anno.index.split('_')[:2])
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [66], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 anno = pd.read_csv(directory_path + "GSE159115_ccRCC_anno.csv.gz", compression="gzip", header=0, sep=",", on_bad_lines="warn", index_col=0)
----> 2 anno.index = ','.join(str(v) for v in anno.index)
      3 '_'.join(anno.index.split('_')[:2])

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:6002, in NDFrame.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   6000 try:
   6001     object.__getattribute__(self, name)
-> 6002     return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   6003 except AttributeError:
   6004     pass

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx:69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:729, in NDFrame._set_axis(self, axis, labels)
    723 @final
    724 def _set_axis(self, axis: AxisInt, labels: AnyArrayLike | list) -> None:
    725     """
    726     This is called from the cython code when we set the `index` attribute
    727     directly, e.g. `series.index = [1, 2, 3]`.
    728     """
--> 729     labels = ensure_index(labels)
    730     self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
    731     self._clear_item_cache()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:7128, in ensure_index(index_like, copy)
   7126         return Index(index_like, copy=copy, tupleize_cols=False)
   7127 else:
-> 7128     return Index(index_like, copy=copy)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:516, in Index.__new__(cls, data, dtype, copy, name, tupleize_cols)
    513         data = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=_dtype_obj)
    515 elif is_scalar(data):
--> 516     raise cls._raise_scalar_data_error(data)
    517 elif hasattr(data, "__array__"):
    518     return Index(np.asarray(data), dtype=dtype, copy=copy, name=name)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:5066, in Index._raise_scalar_data_error(cls, data)
   5061 @final
   5062 @classmethod
   5063 def _raise_scalar_data_error(cls, data):
   5064     # We return the TypeError so that we can raise it from the constructor
   5065     #  in order to keep mypy happy
-> 5066     raise TypeError(
   5067         f"{cls.__name__}(...) must be called with a collection of some "
   5068         f"kind, {repr(data)} was passed"
   5069     )

TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'SI_18854_AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1,SI_18854_AAACCTGTCCACTGGG-1,SI_18854_AAACCTGTCCTTTCTC-1,SI_18854_AAACGGGCAAACTGCT-1,SI_18854_AAACGGGCAAGGTTTC-1' was passed
```

Input:

```
Index(['SI_18854_AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1', 'SI_18854_AAACCTGTCCACTGGG-1',
       'SI_18854_AAACCTGTCCTTTCTC-1', 'SI_18854_AAACGGGCAAACTGCT-1',
       'SI_18854_AAACGGGCAAGGTTTC-1'],
      dtype='object', name='cell', length=20748)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method and specific regex pattern:

```
anno.index.str.extract(r'^([^_]+_[^_]+)_', expand=False)
```

---

```
Index(['SI_18854', 'SI_18854', 'SI_18854', 'SI_18854', 'SI_18854'], dtype='object')
```